# Why does i print a value of 3 in the following code?

Tags: c

The outut of the code below is: `3 2 15`
I was expecting `2 2 15`
Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[5] = { 5, 1, 15, 20, 25 };
    i = ++a[1];
    j = a[1]++;
    m = a[i++];
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could have used a debugger to step through the code to inspect what it was doing...

Comment: [no-effort-expended post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: @Abhishek Aggarwal: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote those that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The increment/decrement operators actually change the value of the object, not just return the resulting value. In the line `m=a[i++];` you are incrementing `i` again.

Answer (score 1):

becuase you increment it twice:

```
i=++a[1];     // i = 2
j=a[1]++;
m=a[i++];     // i = 3
printf("%d %d %d",i,j,m);
```

Comment: Yeah! I was just paying attention to the value of m and not i. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I want it to help you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
i=++a[1]; // i = 2
j=a[1]++; // j = 2
m=a[i++]; // m = 15, i = 3
printf("%d %d %d",i,j,m);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[5] = { 5, 1, 15, 20, 25 };
    i = ++a[1];
    j = a[1]++;
    m = a[i++];
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Lets go through this step by step..

- a[1] is 1
- i is ++1 that is.... 2
- m is a[i] that is a[2] which is... 15

After this statement i++ is executed, so

after m = 15,

i becomes 3,

These values are printed using printf

Answer (score 0):

Lets proceed step by step:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[5] = { 5, 1, 15, 20, 25 };
    i = ++a[1];  // a[1] is incremented, becomes 2, i gets this value 2
    j = a[1]++;  // j gets a[1] which is 2, then a[1] is incremented and becomes 3
    m = a[i++];  // m gets a[2] which is 15, i is incremented and becomes 3
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, m);  // prints 3 2 15
    return 0;
}
```